# How to avoid clipped trash-labels in static image generated with MapBox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio, static

I choose "Generate static image" and select settings and area. All looks correct in the map. Then I enter the generated URL in a browser and look at the image; clipped trash-labels appear that wasn't there before:
[image]

For example: lower left corner, "A. D &" appears. Mid lower left above label "H mart" the text "nford" appears.
The default Mapbox Streets-style was used.

Also left an issue on github repository mapbox-studio-classic; issues 1572. Do you know of any workaround?